# RegExp keyword escaping

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function that changes the HTML of selected elements..

```
$('p').fill('John'); // "John"
```

..that replaces `$value` with the current HTML..

```
$('p').fill('Hi $value.') // "Hi John."
```

..too often.

```
// Should be "The keyword is $value."
$('p').fill('The keyword is \$value.'); // "The keyword is \Hi John.."
```

I currently use this to parse the value..

```
value.replace(/\$value/gi, item.innerHTML);
```

..and the solution I came up with was..

```
value.replace(/[^\\]\$value/gi, '$1' + item.innerHTML);
```

..but in certain cases, it doesn't work.

```
// Ends up with "$value John."
$('p').fill('Hi') // Yes, it supports stacking.
    .fill('$value John.'); // Should be "Hi John."
```

I've also tried..

```
value.replace(/[^\\]?\$value/gi, '$1' + item.innerHTML);
```

..but that has multiple problems.

- If the non-backslash character isn't matched, then `$1` isn't replaced, and I get stuck with that being inserted randomly.
- If it's optional, there could still a backslash there, and then we get stuck with a random backslash, AND the `$1`.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is the escape character in a string, so using one won't make it appear in the string. Try using two of them. You will be left with a literal `\`.

You can get negative lookbehinds in JavaScript regex by using a `Function` as the replacement argument.

```
var result = str.replace(/(.)(\$value)/, function(all, precedingChar, matched) {

   if (precedingChar == '\\') {
        return matched;
    }

    return precedingChar + 'hi John';
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/5ZwHX/).

This function will do exactly as you had it, but if you precede the match with a `\\`, it will return the string unchanged.

Comment: My question is how to skip over `$value` if it has a backslash before it.

Comment: @tyler If there is a preceding backslash, do you want it to be returned?

Comment: No. I want `$value` to turn into whatever the HTML is, and `\$value` to turn into `$value`.

Comment: @tyler As I said, a \ in a string will escape the next character and won't be taken literally, so you must use two, i.e. \\.

Comment: To the parser it will only appear as 1. I'm talking from the parsers point of view.